# Sharing @functions between Orchard custom theme's views

Tags: function, razor, themes, share, orchardcms

I'm porting an existing site in orchard, unfortunately the existing css is not very well stuctured and i need several helper functions to make the site work correctly.

currently i'm rewriting these conversion functions in each of the shape's alternate .cshtml file i'm customizing.

It is always the same function, and i want to move it in some location to make it reusable and more easilly maintanable.

I would also like to have it theme-specific (inside the folder of the theme i'm creating)

the function is very trivial

```
@functions{
string ConvertColorToStyle(string color){
    string menuStyle = "";
    switch(color)
    {
        case "Azure": menuStyle = "secondary_nav_area"; break;
        case "DarkGreen": menuStyle = "secondary_nav_areaDiscoServices"; break;
        case "LightGreen": menuStyle = "secondary_nav_areaPreClinAndClinical"; break;
        case "Violet": menuStyle = "secondary_nav_areaAPI"; break;
        case "LightViolet": menuStyle = "secondary_nav_areaSSC"; break;
        case "DarkAzure": menuStyle = "secondary_nav_areaPharma"; break;
        case "DeepAzure": menuStyle = "secondary_nav_areaIDFDaM"; break;
        case "DeepBlue": menuStyle = "secondary_nav_areaIDDS"; break;
        case "Orange": menuStyle = "secondary_nav_areaClinServices"; break;
        case "Cyan": menuStyle = "secondary_nav_areaConsulting"; break;
        case "Indigo": menuStyle = "secondary_nav_areaINDiGO"; break;
        case "LightAzure": menuStyle = "secondary_nav_areaPAC"; break;
        default: menuStyle = "secondary_nav_area";
        break;
    }
    return menuStyle;
}}
```

but i want to share it across views like what it is possible to do by putting a function.cshtml file in the App_Code folder of an asp.net mvc project.

Is there a way to share this function across all the views in my theme in Orchard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure: add a project file to your theme that has the same name as the theme, then add a cs file to it with a static class that exposes that method. You'll then be able to use the function in your views.

Comment: Works! thanks! just a note for myself: the project can be a normal Windows library project but it is required that the AssemblyInfo.cs file is present. the methods in the defined static class are then accessible bu declaring the @using directive and the namespace of the project (by default is the name of the theme) is the n possible to access the static method specifing the name of the class as well of the method itself like in a normal mvc application. It is not required that the project is compiled, orchard dynamically compile itself automatically

Comment: Another note: it is required to restart IISExpress upon every modification on the .cs file in the project in order to allow orchard to pick up the latest version